# Build failure when generating site with maven-site-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

After having merged a big set of changes from the projects master branch into my own branch, the build performed by the CI server configured with 'mvn package site' now fails ('mvn package' works fine). The site generation also works on my local development machine running win7.
The maven-site-plugin 3.3 is being used (as there where other issues using 3.0)

I can't find any useful hint in the stack trace shown at the end of the maven build:

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project pms-core: Error during page generation
cause : Error during page generation
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project pms-core: Error during page generation
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:104)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during page generation
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.RendererException: Error rendering Maven report: 
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - An error occurred during diagram generation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find an insertion point.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find an insertion point.
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.instrumentDiagram(APIviz.java:322)
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.generateOverviewSummary(APIviz.java:187)
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.start(APIviz.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)

Command line was: /opt/java/sdk/Sun/x86_64/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/scratch/jenkins/workspace/taconaut/pms-mlx/core/target/site/testapidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: 
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - An error occurred during diagram generation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find an insertion point.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find an insertion point.
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.instrumentDiagram(APIviz.java:322)
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.generateOverviewSummary(APIviz.java:187)
    at org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz.start(APIviz.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)

Command line was: /opt/java/sdk/Sun/x86_64/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/scratch/jenkins/workspace/taconaut/pms-mlx/core/target/site/testapidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:4997)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:1975)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.TestJavadocReport.executeReport(TestJavadocReport.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocReport.generate(JavadocReport.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:228)
    ... 33 more
channel stopped
```

Can someone point me into the right direction? Is this a bug of the maven-site-plugin or something I should adapt in my code?

Git repository: https://github.com/taconaut/pms-mlx

CI: https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/job/taconaut/job/pms-mlx/ (build #39 failed because of this issue, for build #40 I've removed the site generation to have a working CI)

[update] Googling for the message 'An error occurred during diagram generation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find an insertion point.', I've found the source of the exception in the [apiviz library](https://code.google.com/p/apiviz/source/browse/tags/apiviz-1.1.3/src/main/java/net/gleamynode/apiviz/APIviz.java?r=319#160). This makes me think it's a library bug, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by updating the version of apiviz library to the latest version.